# typeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Web3Provider') How to Fix it

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, ethers.js

import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { abi , contractAddress } from  '../config.json'
import { ethers } from 'ethers';

export const BlockchainContext = React.createContext();

export const BlockchainProvider = ({children}) => {

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
const signer = provider.getSigner()
const address = contractAddress;
const contractAbi = abi;
const contract= new ethers.Contract(address, contractAbi, signer);
return(
    <BlockchainContext.Provider
    value={{}} >
        {children}
    </BlockchainContext.Provider>
)
```

}